# Subshell in a function cannot find basic bash commands when called from another function

Tags: bash, eval, subshell

I have the following bash script (this is a simplified version of a more complex script).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x

function execute() {
    `$1` # same as $($1), gives "command not found" as do all the following:
    # $1 # or ${1}
    # eval "$1"
    # eval $1

    # This gives "No such file or directory" even though it *is* there...
    #"$1"
}

function runCommand() {
    PATH="${1}"
    execute "chmod 777 ${PATH}"
}

execute "chmod 777 ${1}"
runCommand "$1"

#EOF
```

When I run it I get the following output:

```
+ execute 'chmod 777 build.test-case.sh'
++ chmod 777 build.test-case.sh
+ runCommand build.test-case.sh
+ PATH=build.test-case.sh
+ execute 'chmod 777 build.test-case.sh'
++ chmod 777 build.test-case.sh
./build.test-case.sh: line 5: chmod: command not found
```

So `chmod` works when the `execute` function is called directly but fails when it is called from another function, even though the debug output seems to be exactly the same...

**Can anyone explain this behaviour?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are overwriting the [**PATH**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) variable, which contains the paths to the directories where the binaries are, like the `chmod` one, so that's why it can't find it.

If you use another variable, instead of the `PATH` one, for your `runCommand()` function, it should work, like this:

```
function runCommand() {
    VAR="${1}"
    execute "chmod 777 ${VAR}"
}
```

Comment: Well, that's egg on my face, then. That'll teach me to not adhere to my own standards of never using all caps vars. :-)